# CSS custom sprites

Tags: css, background-image, sprite

I have a sprite (110px height x 50px width) of images (50px x 50px) with 10px between them.

I have `<li>` with a padding and a margin, a width isn't static, a height - 80px.

I want to place the image 50x50 (from 61px to 110px (h) and 0 to 50 (w)) in `<li>` as its background on a left (horizontally) in a middle (vertically) not changing the width/height of `<li>`.

Lot's of articles have been read by me... I didn't find a normal solution. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can set the background position in the CSS. Background position will accept negative numbers too. Set the size of the li and display it as a block element then play around with the background position: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/CSS/background-position